# VBA Input Box data validation on specific number format

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for way to validate my input in Macro, I want my input to be restricted to XXXXXX-XXX (eg. 465824-456). This is the code I've tried (adapted from recording macro in data validation):

```
Lot = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter Lot ID to be put into Storage :", Type:=0)

If Lot = "=AND(ISNUMBER(LEFT(Lot,6)+0),MID(Lot,7,1)=""-"",ISNUMBER(RIGHT(Lot,3)+0))" Then
```

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Like" Statement

```
If Lot Like "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]" Then
```